# Wordpress problema com template para acessar a página

Tags: php, html

Eu saquei um template para fazer um site para mim
e esta me a dar um erro no qual nao estou a perceber
Queria ajuda

Isto é tipo uma loja online no qual tera uma serie de produtos á venda

e quando coloco os ficheiro no localhost só me aparece a mensagem que esta presente em baixo
e nao sei como resolver
no php tenho este codigo

```
<?php
// File Security Check
if ( ! function_exists( 'wp' ) && ! empty( $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'] ) && basename( __FILE__ ) == basename( $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'] ) ) {
    die ( 'You do not have  permissions to access this page!' );
}
?><?php
/**
 * Index Template
 *
 * Here we setup all logic and XHTML that is required for the index template, used as both the homepage
 * and as a fallback template, if a more appropriate template file doesn't exist for a specific context.
 *
 * @package WooFramework
 * @subpackage Template
 */
    get_header();
    global $woo_options;

?>
```

e no browser aparece isto ~

You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page!~

Não esta a aparecer o conteudo
O que estará mal nessa linha de codigo ou é preciso alguma base de dados
Obrigado

Comment: conseguem me ajudar?

Comment: Sua pergunta está meio dificil de entender, tem como você editar e melhorar um pouco?

Answer (score 0):

verifica o valor destes termos:

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'wp' ) && ! empty( $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'] ) && basename( __FILE__ ) == basename( $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'] ) ) {
    die ( 'You do not have  permissions to access this page!' );
}
```

caso não interfira no funcionamento da ferramenta comenta esse **if** e monitora o funcionamento.